# View MDX used in Cube browser

Tags: ssas, mdx, sql-server-profiler, olap-cube

I am trying to see the MDX which is used in Cube Browser. I searched on google and once again I am being redirected StackOverflow's post  [View MDX query generated while browsing a cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321453/view-mdx-query-generated-while-browsing-a-cube)

Yes, I can see the MDX but when I try to execute the same MDX (copied from Profiler and pasted in SSMS) in SSMS- Analysis server, it does not executes and gives me error.

Am I doing something wrong here? If not, is there any other way to get the MDX out of the cube?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the MDX here and we can have a look.

Comment: Snapshot of the MDX: 

'http://s10.postimage.org/5evzximyx/SQL_Server_Profiler_Untitled_3_INGGN1_EDR8_P.jpg'

Comment: Please edit your question - don't put it in a comment

Comment: @PreetSangha: I have not edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some deep analysis, I have found that SQL Profiler is more awesome tool which helps you to get this query.

What you need to do is Capture all the query between the batch operations and then put them in MDX Query pane in SSMS.

You can execute them one by one and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to have the error message, but I guess the definition of this set (?) is missing :

```
select non empty [{73C699C7-F74B-48A7-96AE-E131412D0725}Pivot73Axis0Set0] ...
```

from your request. Somehow you should have a WITH SET ... in the MDX request as well.

Comment: Executing the query ...
Query (1, 150) The dimension '[{73C699C7-F74B-48A7-96AE-E131412D0725}Pivot73Axis1Set0]' was not found in the cube when the string, [{73C699C7-F74B-48A7-96AE-E131412D0725}Pivot73Axis1Set0], was parsed.
Query (1, 18) The dimension '[{73C699C7-F74B-48A7-96AE-E131412D0725}Pivot73Axis0Set0]' was not found in the cube when the string, [{73C699C7-F74B-48A7-96AE-E131412D0725}Pivot73Axis0Set0], was parsed.

Execution complete

Comment: This confirm my response; the definition of this set is missing; if you cannot get it from your Cube Browser then your MDX is not valide. Do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I agree with you that MDX is not valid but I have copied it from Profiler directly. 

Might be possible I am focusing on wrong event. Can you suggest me with event should I look for?

Comment: No idea - do not know at all the tool you're using. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I tried working this out and consulted number of forums but could not get an absolute  answer.

But I found a way around for the same using MS EXcel and a plugin http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the creation of the set `[{73C699C7-F74B-48A7-96AE-E131412D0725}Pivot73Axis0Set0]`

It's probably a few line before the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

If you have EXCEL 2010 installed + PowerPivot plugin...

So you open excel 2010 you go to "Powerpivot Icon" you try to open a new connexion ...Then you'll see a window title "MDX STATEMENT" you choose design...

When you finishe designing your cube Y'll see the MDX Statement related...